# Como uso el valor de un return de un método en otro método ambos métodos dentro de la misma clase

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public static double Calcula_Importe(double precio_sin_iva,int cantidad,double iva){

    double total_importe;
    double precio_con_iva;
    double iva_producto;

    iva_producto=iva*precio_sin_iva;
    precio_con_iva=iva_producto+precio_sin_iva;
    total_importe=cantidad*precio_con_iva;
    return total_importe ; // ESTE ES EL VALOR QUE QUIERO UTILIZAR EN EL 
                              METODO DE ABAJO      


}         

 public void Consulta_Pedidos(){  



   System.out.println("\t Seccion de Pedidos");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Numero de Pedido: "+num_pedido);
   System.out.println("FECHA ACTUAL");
   System.out.println("   Dia: "+dia_actual);
   System.out.println("   Mes: "+mes_actual);
   System.out.println("   Año: "+año_actual);
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("FECHA DEL PEDIDO");
   System.out.println("   Dia: "+dia_pedido);
   System.out.println("   Mes: "+mes_pedido);
   System.out.println("   Año: "+año_pedido);
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Nombre del Cliente: "+nombre_cliente);
   System.out.println("Producto: "+producto);
   System.out.println("Cantidad: "+cantidad);
   System.out.println("Precio sin Iva: "+precio_sin_iva); 
   System.out.println("IMPORTE TOTAL: "+);// PARA CONCATENARLO AQUI

 }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando usas `void` en un método, estás indicando que ese método no retorna nada (`void` significa `vacío`), por lo que no podrás usar ningún valor que se genere dentro de ese método en otra parte. Si quieres usar lo que el método devuelve deberás cambiar su declaración, cambiando `void` por el tipo de dato que devolverá el método (`String`, `int`, `boolean`, etc) y la última sentencia del método deberá ser un `return valorARetornar;`. Puedes [consultar la doc al respecto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste ha pasarle el importe por parámetro? , Debe de quedar algo así:

```
public void Consulta_Pedidos(double importe){
```

Y en la última línea:

```
System.out.println("IMPORTE TOTAL: "+ importe);
}
```

Es una solución rápida y eficiente.
A ver: me falta información sobre tu programa pero te expongo aquí a efectos generales:
Si es una función creada dentro de la clase principal, tendrá que ser static para llamarla así:

```
Consulta_pedidos(1000.50);
```

Pero si viene de una clase aparte, con su constructor creado y demás, tendrás que instanciarla y luego usar su método. Algo como así:

Imaginemos que parte de la clase Pedido:

```
Pedido ped = new Pedido(); 
ped.Consulta_pedidos(1000.50);
```

Sin saber más de tu programa no te puedo dar una explicación más detallada.

Comment: y para mandar a llamar el metodo                                                                                                   public void Consulta_Pedidos(double importe){                                                                     a la clase principal como lo haria? solo me faltaria eso ayudame porfavor y gracias por contesarme

Comment: Revisa la respuesta porque he añadido información sobre tu problema

Comment: @AntonioTomeroHerrero Por favor, intenta usar las convenciones del lenguaje cuando escribes tu código: los métodos deben nombrarse empezando con minúscula y en formato *camelCase*: `consultaPedidos(...)` y `calculaImporte(...)`

Comment: @Pablo Lozano: Eso yo lo sé pero para responderle a su pregunta he intentado respetarle sus nombres para que no se confundiera. No vaya a ser que por escribirlo bien no sea el usuario con duda capaz de entender mi respuesta. Pero gracias por la aclaración, me faltó indicarle eso en mi respuesta a su problema.

Comment: Perdona, tienes toda la razón, el comentario debería ir a @BestJhonny, ya es tarde para editarlo :(